# Looping over a string list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list which consists of a different colours, all stored as string variables.

```
Preferredcolours = ['red','yellow','green', 'blue']
```

I have a panda array, which contains information about cars. One of the column  DfCar['colour'] consists of the colours of these cars.  I want to create a new variable in my data frame, column named PreferredMathcing which =1 if the DataFrame colour column matches with one of the list colours. How can I use a for loop to solve this?

I would ideally want this sort of a solution:

```
+=================+============================+
| DfCar['colour'] | DfCar['PreferredMathcing'] |
+=================+============================+
| white           |                          0 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
| yellow          |                          1 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
| black           |                          0 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
| purple          |                          0 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
| green           |                          1 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: By pandas array, do you mean a dataframe?

Comment: Please provide an example input as well.

Comment: `df['PreferredMatching'] = df[df.colour.isin(PreferredColours)].astpye(int)`

Comment: @Saif you got a lot of working solutions, if your data is big I suggest you benchmark them and choose the one that performs best... from my experience, using `apply(...)` for simple stuff can take x20 - x30 times more then a dedicated function. that is - half an hour instead of 1m, or a full day instead of 1h...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), which returns a Series with `True`/`False` for each row based on if it is in a list of values. then use `.astype(int)` to get your `1`/`0` instead.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'colour': ['white', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple', 'green']})
Preferredcolours = ['red','yellow','green', 'blue']

df["PreferredMathcing"] = df['colour'].isin(Preferredcolours).astype(int)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   colour  PreferredMathcing
0   white                  0
1  yellow                  1
2   black                  0
3  purple                  0
4   green                  1
```

**NOTE:**

choosing a solution with a pure library function will likely out-perform a solution using `apply` with custom python logic.

bench-marking those against each other on my machine suggests `.isin()` is almost x8 faster:

```py
with '.isin()': 1.0591506958007812
with '.apply()': 8.234664678573608
ratio: 7.774780974248154
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.where like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DfCar = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'colour': ['white', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple', 'green']})
Preferredcolours = ['red','yellow','green', 'blue']

DfCar['PreferredMathcing'] = np.where(DfCar['colour'].isin(Preferredcolours), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

following will give you output

```
def check_colour(x, Preferredcolours) :
    return 1 if x['colour'] in Preferredcolours else 0

dfCar['PreferredMathcing'] = df.apply(check_colour,args=(Preferredcolours,), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DfCar` is your Dataframe.

```
Preferredcolours = ['red','yellow','green', 'blue']    
DfCar['PreferredMatching'] = DfCar['colour'].apply(lambda x: x in Preferredcolours)
```

This will apply the lambda function over every element in your "colour" column. Simply check if it is in "preferredcolours" and return True or False.